# In place construction for class with deleted move and copy constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, move

Assume I have a class with deleted copy and move constructors. I'd like to have a factory function that constructs the object in place depending on some bool `x`, without allocating dynamic memory (no unique_ptr, new, etc).

Two questions:

1. Why does the below throw a `use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&&)'`? Where is the move happening?
2. How can I achieve something to the effect of what I'm trying to do?

Thanks. Code below:

**EDITED**:

What I'm trying to do is create a single factory function that can create either a parent or a child depending on some variable X. This construction needs to be in-place given deleted copy/move.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int _x) : x(_x) {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(const Foo&&) = delete;
    int x = 10;;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar(int _y) : Foo(10), y(_y) {}
    int y;
};

Foo make_dynamic(int a, bool x) {
    if (x) {
        return Foo{a};
    } else {
        return Bar{a};
    }
}

Foo make_just_foo(int a)
{
    return Foo{a};
}

Foo make_just_bar(int a)
{
    return Bar{a};
}

int main() {
    Foo&& dynamic = make_dynamic(10, true); // works when copy/move not deleted
    Foo&& f = make_just_foo(10);
    Foo &&b2 = make_just_bar(10); // works when copy/move not deleted
}
```

New Link: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7a3eefd685f0adb

Comment: But what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Looks like you want `Foo x{10};`.

Comment: @juanchopanza updated what I really want. I want a factory function that can create either Foo or Bar. The catch is that it needs to be in-place due to deleted copy/move. Bar inherits from Foo

Comment: That won't work if you're returning by value (object slicing.) I suggest looking into _type erasure_ if you have a unbounded set of types you want to support, or `std::variant` if bounded.

Comment: what is the purpose of `make_dynamic` when it is always returning a `Foo`?

Comment: You say you want an object to be created "in-place". What do you mean by that? In what place, or in place of what? How does the factory function know what place the object needs to be created in?

Comment: @BobBills did you not see the if-else? Bar is a subclass of Foo. Please make sure you understand before commenting.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I suggest reading up on what in-place means in C++

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you're right with your last comment. Happy to place a correct answer if you put it into an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @darksky it does not matter that you create a Bar when you return a Foo by value,  the Foo part of Bar is copy/moved, not the entire Bar. You can't recover the Bar from the resulting Foo. It does not work like using a pointer to base class, those are values.

Comment: @BobBills Now I understand what you mean: yes you're right, I know. That was for illustration of what I'd like it to do (I should have used templates there to make it clearer).

Comment: I know what "in-place" means in C++. It's not clear what you mean by it. Say, a placement new creates an object "in-place" by actually taking a pointer to a place in which to create it. But your `make_dynamic` does not.

Comment: The types of all expressions must be known at compile-time, there is no possible way that `Foo&& dynamic = make_dynamic(10, true);` can work as you intended. (Supposing `true` might be an expression not known at compile-time, that is). You actually have to use the appropriately-named dynamic allocation for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could make this work was to use a `union`, (since I could not make it to work using `std::variant` nor `std::any` since both of them require Foo and Bar to be at least movable)

You need a Dynamic struct to act as a return type:

```
// acts as home made std::variant
struct Dynamic {
    union {
        Foo foo;
        Bar bar;
    };

    int active;
};
```

and construct it using designated initializers C++20 but already is and works in current GCC and Clang:

```
Dynamic make_dynamic(int a, bool x) {
    if (x) {
        return {{.foo = Foo{2}}, 0};
    } else {
        return {{.bar = Bar{2}}, 1};
    }
}
```

And finally we can get our dynamic Foo:

```
Dynamic dynamic = make_dynamic(10, true);
Foo* foo = dynamic.get();
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7JWB6D

You can also add getFoo() and getBar() methods to return references to the `Dynamic` struct.